# Why MongoDB support transaction?

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, transactions

WiredTiger supports document-level concurrency, so operation will be rejected if another user accesses the same document at the same time. If two users run the operation on the same document at the same time, only one of them is allowed to perform the operation, and the other has a conflict. So why does mongoDB support transaction additionally? What is the role of transaction in mongoDB?

Comment: It is there to offer the same guarantee when multiple documents are involved.

Comment: Read this: [MongoDB Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/transactions/index.html).